# Pandas column tolist() while each row data being list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tolist

I am trying to save & read a data frame that has following formatting

```
index    sentence
 0       ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
 1       ['dd', 'ee', 'ff']
```

When I read the saved csv file and turn the 'sentence' column into a list using tolist(),
the created list treats

"['aa', 'bb', 'cc']" as a string (including the brackets and ')

Is there a way to read the column as list of lists of strings? [['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], ['dd', 'ee', 'ff']] ...

Or recommended formatting when saving the sentence column in the first place?

Comment: In general it is not recommended to include a list into a dataframe and as such it can lead to some difficulties like this. This is usually also not recommended, but in this case you can probably use the `eval` function to turn the string into an actual list again. Note that `eval` can lead to security issues, so only do this if you trust the data contained within the `sentence` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with the saving method. CSVs are not natively able to store lists unless you specifically parse them after reading.

Would it be possible for you to save time and effort by saving in another format instead? JSON natively supprots lists and is also a format that can be easily read by humans.

Here is an obligatory snippet for you:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"sentence":['aa', 'bb', 'cc']},{"sentence":['dd', 'ee', 'ff']}])

df.to_json("myfile.json")
df2 = pd.read_json("myfile.json")
```

Giving the following result:

```
>>> df2
       sentence
0  [aa, bb, cc]
1  [dd, ee, ff]
```